# UIPickerView weird behavior when scrolling to previous items

Tags: ios, swift

Im building a UIPickerView that uses viewForRow datasource method different from usual titleForRow and im facing problems probably because of the view arc or render rule for the preview.

When im scrolling the component, the previous (left) item cant be seen on the main window, only when he's halfway to take the main window (around 50%); what it bugs me is that the right item seems to work fine.

[image: Image right before the point to appear]
[image: Image right after the point before]

Ive tried a lot of frame manipulation, be it the content view or the frame, it doesnt seem to matter.

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
        let view = MTGCardViewPicker()
        view.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: -rotationAngle)
        ImageDownloader.setMagicCard(with: cards[row].literalImageURL(), imageView: &view.imageView)

        return view
    }
```

I want it to feel more fluid.

Comment: UIPickerView is not designed to be used horizontally, or with rows that big, it's not surprising that you're running into issues. I would suggest using a collection view.

Comment: For any but the simplest case, I've switched to UICollectionView and then (mostly) emulated the picker behavior.